# WPF MVVM DataGrid populate with query at run time

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

Being new to WPF and MVVM I've been struggling for the last few days trying to solve this issue. I've searched all over stackoverflow and google/Youtube for help.

I have a DataGrid (biound from OrderListView) that is populated from a BindableCollection (Caliburn Micro) of a model. However I need to bring in a property ('Program') of linked data from another BindableCollection ProductList, (both collections share a common property 'Code'.

Basically I want the DataGrid to show all the OrderModel based columns and fill a column called Programs with the related data from the Products collection just at run time.

**OrderModel.cs**

```
public class OrderModel : BaseModel
    {
        private DateTime _orderDate;
        public DateTime OrderDate
        {
            get { return _orderDate; }
            set { _orderDate = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private string _code;
        public string Code
        {
            get { return _code; }
            set { _code = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private int _qty;
        public int Qty
        {
            get { return _qty; }
            set { _qty = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }
```

**ProductModel.cs**

```
public class ProductModel : BaseModel
    {
        private string _code;
        public string Code
        {
            get { return _code; }
            set { _code = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private int _program;
        public int Program
        {
            get { return _program; }
            set { _program = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }
```

**DataGrid** in OrderView.xaml

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding OrderListView}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Code}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Qty}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Program}"/>  <- This from ProductList ??
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

**OrderViewModel.cs**

```
public class OrderViewModel : Screen
{
        private readonly IDataConnection _connect;

        private ICollectionView _orderView;
        public ICollectionView OrderListView
        {
            get => _orderView;
            set
            {
                _orderView = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => OrderListView);
            }
        }

        private BindableCollection<OrderModel> _orderList;
        public BindableCollection<OrderModel> OrderList
        {
            get => _orderList;
            set
            {
                _orderList = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => OrderList);
            }
        }

        private BindableCollection<ProductModel> _productList;
        public BindableCollection<ProductModel> ProductList
        {
            get { return _productList; }
            set { _productList = value; }
        }

        private string _code;
        public string Code
        {
            get { return _code; }
            set { _code = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Code); }
        }

        private int _qty;
        public int Qty
        {
            get { return _qty; }
            set { _qty = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Qty); }
        }

        private int _program;
        public int Program
        {
            get { return _program; }
            set
            {
                _program = value;

                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Program);
            }
        }

        public OrderViewModel(IDataConnection connect)
        {
            DisplayName = "Orders";

            var allOrders = await _connect.Orders_GetByDateRange(StartDate, EndDate);
            OrderList = new BindableCollection<OrderModel>(allOrders);
            OrderListView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(OrderList);

            var allProducts = await _connect.Products_GetAll();
            ProductList = new BindableCollection<ProductModel>(allProducts);
        }
}
```

Basically where 'Code' Matches in the models i want to pull the associated Program into the column.

Answer (score 0):

The `ItemsSource` that a `DataGrid` binds to needs to contain all the properties for the column bindings.

Which means either a `Program` property needs to be added to your current `OrderModel` or create a new model that contains both properties.

```
public class OrderModel : BaseModel
{
    private DateTime _orderDate;
    public DateTime OrderDate
    {
        get { return _orderDate; }
        set { _orderDate = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private string _code;
    public string Code
    {
        get { return _code; }
        set { _code = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private int _qty;
    public int Qty
    {
        get { return _qty; }
        set { _qty = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private int _program;
    public int Program
    {
        get { return _program; }
        set { _program = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}
```

Then there will be logic needed to link the new `Program` value with the value from the other collection.

The cleanest place for this would most likely be to modify your query (assuming you are using a database connection)

Most likely this would be to include a `JOIN` when doing the selection for the Orders.

However, doing this on the client side, meaning after the data has been recieved from the `IDataConnection` would look like this:

```
using System.Linq;
...

public OrderViewModel(IDataConnection connect)
{
    DisplayName = "Orders";

    var allOrders = await _connect.Orders_GetByDateRange(StartDate, EndDate);

    var allProducts = await _connect.Products_GetAll();
    ProductList = new BindableCollection<ProductModel>(allProducts);

    foreach(var order in allOrders)
    {
        //assumes "Code" is unique within `ProductList`
        order.Program = ProductList.Single(p => p.Code == order.Code);
    }
    OrderList = new BindableCollection<OrderModel>(allOrders);
    OrderListView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(OrderList);
}
```